Stream Chat implementation in NextJS and using Auth0 for user login
I am trying to set up a chat system within my application and planning to use the stream-chat sdk.
I was following some examples and some how not able to get it through.
This is my page
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Chat,
  Channel,
  ChannelList,
  Window,
  ChannelHeader,
  MessageList,
  MessageInput,
  Thread,
  useCreateChatClient,
} from "stream-chat-react";
import { StreamChat } from "stream-chat";
import axios from "axios";

import "stream-chat-react/dist/css/index.css";
import { useUser } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client";
import AppChat from "@/components/Messages/AppChat";

const chatClient = new StreamChat(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STREAM_API_KEY);

function MyMessagesPage() {
  const { user } = useUser();
  //const username = user.email.replace(/([^a-z0-9_-]+)/gi, "_");
  const username = user?.sub.replace(/([^a-z0-9_-]+)/gi, "_");

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-screen flex flex-col items-center px-8 pt-8 custom">
      {user && <AppChat user={user} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyMessagesPage;

The chat window is the followng:
'use client';

import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StreamChat, ChannelSort, ChannelFilters } from 'stream-chat';
import {
    Channel,
    ChannelHeader,
    ChannelList,
    Chat,
    MessageInput,
    MessageList,
    Thread,
    Window,
} from 'stream-chat-react';
import ChannelListHeader from './ChannelListHeader';
import axios from 'axios';
import { UserProfile } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0/client';

export default function AppChat({ user }: { user: UserProfile }) {
    const apiKey = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STREAM_API_KEY || 'Set API Key';


    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const chatClient = StreamChat.getInstance(apiKey);

    const sort: ChannelSort = { last_message_at: -1 };
    const filters: ChannelFilters = {
        type: 'messaging',
        members: { $in: [user.sub] },
    };

    const chatUser = chatClient.user;

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('The user', user);
        const fetchToken = async () => {
            let token;
            try {
                const response = await axios.post("/api/messages", { user });
                token = response.data.token;
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('Error fetching token:', err);
                setIsLoading(true);
                return;
            }

            await chatClient.connectUser({ id: user.sub }, token);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchToken();

    }, [user]);

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading && (
                <div className="text-white w-full flex items-center justify-center">
                    <p>Loading…</p>
                </div>
            )}
            {!isLoading && (
                <div id="root">
                    <Chat client={chatClient}>
                        <div className="channel-list-container">
                            <ChannelListHeader user={chatUser} />
                            <ChannelList sort={sort} filters={filters} showChannelSearch />
                        </div>
                        <Channel>
                            <Window>
                                <ChannelHeader />
                                <MessageList />
                                <MessageInput />
                            </Window>
                            <Thread />
                        </Channel>
                    </Chat>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

This is the API (although this si working well) route.ts getting the token.
import { getRequesterSub } from "@/utils/auth";
import { NotAuthorised } from "@/utils/errors";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { StreamChat } from "stream-chat";

// Initialize Stream Chat outside of the handler to use across multiple requests
const serverSideClient = new StreamChat(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STREAM_API_KEY!,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STREAM_APP_SECRET!
);

export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const sub = await getRequesterSub(req);

  if (!sub) {
    return NotAuthorised("User not authenticated");
  }

  const userId = sub.replace(/([^a-z0-9_-]+)/gi, "_");
  const token = serverSideClient.createToken(userId);
  console.log("Token for " + userId, token);

  try {
    await serverSideClient.upsertUser({
      id: userId,
    });
    const admin = { id: "admin" };
    const channel = serverSideClient.channel("team", "chat", {
      name: "Group messaging",
      created_by: admin,
    });

    await channel.create();
    await channel.addMembers([userId]);

    return NextResponse.json({ user: { userId }, token });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to join user:", err);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: err }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

I feel like I am missing something here and mixing things up not able to connectUser
await chatClient.connectUser({ id: user.sub }, token);
because user.sub or user.name has undefined and that cannot be assigned to a string.
Any eyes on this would be really helpful.
I first initially tried creating an interface but failed to get that working.

I think I figured this out. It was just me trying to use the object directly. I should have stored it as userID and compare the sub to the token generated and connect the client
